# Laravel: Using Query Multiple Times with different Wheres

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have been struggling with this for efficiency purpose. Logically, this should work. But, once I call count() or get(), the 2nd usage does not work. If you see the following code, it'll become clear to you:

```
$query = Address::where('area_id',$area->id);
if($order === 'house_no')
    $query->orderBy('house_no','ASC');
$query->join('members as m','addresses.member_id','=','m.id');
if($order === 'reg')
    $query->orderBy('batch','ASC')->orderBy('reg','ASC');
if($types != '')
    $query->whereIn('m.type', explode(',', $types));

$male = $query->where('m.gender','male')->get();
$female = $query->where('m.gender','female')->get(); //this does not work
```

As you can see, calling the `$query` variable in both the `$male` and `$female` should logically work. But I only get the result of the first call, it seems that once the `count()` or `get()` is called, the `$query` variable no longer does anything else.

I have also tried to store `$query` to two different variables for those two collections, but same result.

Any suggestions?

I could do the same thing twice but it would be inefficient (me thinks).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`clone`ing it should work. Otherwise you're operating always on the same builder instance.

```
$maleQuery = clone $query;
$femaleQuery = clone $query;

$male = $maleQuery->where('m.gender','male')->get();
$female = $femaleQuery->where('m.gender','female')->get();
```

Comment: In addition to Lukas answer - even if you buffer the query - the main 'effort' is the SQL call itself - which you have to run twice. There is no way around it.

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter. Life saver. @ The Shift Exchange yes I kept it in mind, but no point writing 16 lines of code twice. Thanks.

Comment: where is `clone` documented in Laravel doc ?

Comment: `clone` is a native php command [Object Clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Answer (score 2):

It's all about those `wheres` not `get` or `count` - basically your last attempt has `where m.gender = male AND m.gender = female`, so it **logically shouldn't** work and it doesn't.

Also mind that storing `$query` in 2 variables does nothing, since **objects are passed by reference**, so despite operating on `$varOne` and `$varTwo` you still use the same object:

```
$query = Address::query();
// add your clauses
$male = $query;
$female = $query;

$male === $female; // true

// but
$male = $query;
$female = clone $query;
$male === $female; // false - 2 different objects

// now you can add last where
$males   = $male->where('m.gender', 'male')->get();
$females = $female->where('m.gender', 'female')->get();
```

Just `clone` the query before using `where('m.gender..)` and you will be fine.